# Python: Pydev: Ctrl+space returns NullPointerException

Tags: python, eclipse, nullpointerexception, pydev

I work in Eclipse using PyDev plugin. Suddenly I started getting NullPointerException when I press Ctrl+Space as you can see on the attached image: [image]

As you can see the variable splitPhrase is already defined in my code.

Have you any idea how to avoid getting this exeption?
Thanks

Comment: Does it happen everywhere?

Comment: @Yes it does, but only when I press ctrl+space.

Comment: Weird. You might want to check if this is happening only in pydev or all of eclipse. Some possible remedies might be reinstalling both eclipse/pydev, updating pydev.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your error log? See: http://pydev.org/faq.html#PyDevFAQ-HowdoIReportaBUG%3F for details

Comment: @FabioZadrozny I'm sorry I see your comment for the first time. I can't find log so here is the log from .metadata/.log (last page): http://pastebin.com/1JnY5KeS

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the issue I believe your bug was already fixed, so, please upgrade to the latest PyDev version to see if it works (3.6.0).

Instructions available at http://pydev.org/download.html (or you can get the latest LiClipse: http://brainwy.github.io/liclipse/ for a standalone with PyDev bundled).

Comment: I've tried to update PyDev but It seem like I have already installed newest version: `PyDev for Eclipse will be ignored because it is already installed, and updates are not permitted.`

Comment: Can you double check the version? (the preferences > pydev preferences page shows the pydev version)

Comment: You have to go to help > install new software (i.e.: as if installing for the first time... see: http://pydev.org/manual_101_install.html) -- or just get the latest LiClipse :)

Comment: That's the problem, I can't do that, when I try it, I get error. 'PyDev for Eclipse will be ignored because it is already installed, and updates are not permitted.'

Comment: Which other plugins are you using?